# Vert.x Auth - Missing authority yields 500 instead of 403

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, vert.x

I am implementing my AuthHandler in Java that works with normal authorities added to each route. It works just fine - it can detect if a user has not passed required fields and can tell if a user is allowed or not to access a route. But if I try to access a forbidden route based on missing authorities vert.x responds with a 500 - Internal Server Error instead of 403 - Forbidden.

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Here are a few code snippets that might help

```java
// MyUserImpl
@Override
    protected void doIsPermitted(String authority, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> resultHandler) {
        //TODO: make call to token to check permissions using crn and iamtoken
        if (this.token.contains(authority)) {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(true));
        } else {
            log.info("User is not authorized", token, authority);
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(new AuthorizationException(authority)));
        }
    }
```

```java
// MyAuthProviderImpl
@Override
    public void authenticate(JsonObject authInfo, Handler<AsyncResult<User>> resultHandler) {
        String token = authInfo.getString("iamToken");
        if (this.validate(token)) {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new TaskUserImpl(token)));
        } else {
            log.info("User cannot be authenticated", token);
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(new AuthenticationException()));
        }
    }
```

```java
// MyAuthHandlerImpl
public void parseCredentials(RoutingContext ctx, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler) {
        this.parseAuthorization(ctx, false, parseAuthorization -> {
            if (parseAuthorization.failed()) {
                log.info("No Auth token was provided");
                handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(parseAuthorization.cause()));
                final String token = parseAuthorization.result();
                handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(
                        new JsonObject()
                            .put("iamToken", iamToken)
                ));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can that be that when the authorities are not provided then you have a nullpointer exception somewhere in the chain? eg. iamToken is null wich leads maybe a to an exception in MyUserImpl this.token.contains... ?

Comment: That can very much be. Is there a good way to debug through this chain? I tried to debug it step by step but I didnt not find any thrown exceptions except the ones i pass back in the handler callbacks.

Comment: Why do you call `parseAuthorization.result();` and handle with succeeded if you already handle failed? You forget } and `else` block? There is not all code from stack to answer the Q. Did you try router.errorHandler(500, rcxt -> {}) to see rctx.failure()?